# Почему radio button возвращает null?

Tags: c#, winforms

Программа считает количество гласных в тексте. При переключении радио кнопки должен меняться язык текста в текстовом поле textBoxOutput. Текст в текстовом поле отображается при клике на кнопку Подсчитать. Радио кнопки находятся в другой форме, они видны в главной форме. При нажатии на кнопку подсчитать выбрасывает исключение System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.", то есть радио кнопки возвращают null. Почему они возвращают null?

Код:

```
private void buttonCountUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Program.f2.radioButtonEnglish.Checked)
    {
       textBoxOutput.Text = textBoxOutput.Text + "Result:" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Гласных: " + glasnie;
    }
    else if (Program.f2.radioButtonRussian.Checked)
    {
       textBoxOutput.Text = textBoxOutput.Text + "Результат:" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Гласных: " + glasnie;
    }
}
```

Вторая форма видна в главной с помощью добавления в class Program в Program.cs

```
static class Program
    {
        public static FormMain f1;
        public static FormSettings f2;
        /// <summary>
        /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(f1 = new FormMain());
            Application.Run(f2 = new FormSettings());
        }
    }
```

Скрины форм с пояснениями:
[image: скрины форм с пояснениями]

Comment: На 3 вещи можно смотреть вечно: как горит огонь, как течёт вода и как студенты не могут воспользоваться дебаггером, чтобы отловить простейший NullReferenceException. Смотреть можно, но не очень хочется

Comment: RadioButton'ы ничего не "возвращают". Это объекты. Они либо есть, либо их нет. Вот только нет не самих RadioButton, а Вашей формы `f2` (навести мышкой на слово во время вылетевшего исключения так сложно, серьезно?), потому что надо хоть немного понимать то, что Вы пишете. Даже не понимая до конца того, как работает `Application.Run`, при не полностью атрофированной логике можно сделать банальный вывод: после этой строчки выполнение программы дальше не идёт, ибо в противном случае мы бы вышли за пределы метода `Main`, то есть программа считалась бы завершённой.

Comment: Расшифровываю: на момент существования формы f1 не существует формы f2. На момент же появления формы f2 форма f1 уже будет закрыта.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov тогда почему я из формы f2 могу изменить фоновый цвет формы f1?

Comment: Из FormSettings Вы можете воздействовать на свойства инстанса объекта FormMain. Но Вы не можете заставить взаимодействовать конкретно объекты `Program.f1` и `Program.f2`, ибо их жизненные циклы не соприкасаются.

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы они смогли взаимодействовать? Соре, просто до 9 утра проект сдать надо

Comment: Уберите к черту эти статические переменные. И запомните: когда Вы создаёте что-то публичное и статическое, Вы создаёте зло. Есть редкие исключения, но чаще всего к Вашему коду они не относятся. Program должен просто запустить FormMain и дождаться, пока эта форма будет закрыта (чем и занимается Application.Run), а уже в FormMain при необходимости Вы должны создать объект FormSettings, передав в его конструктор ссылку на текущий инстанс FormMain

Comment: @Kir_Antipov убрал статические переменные, сделал следующим образом: https://imgur.com/CNpuKN8 , но все равно выдает ту же самую ошибку

Comment: Зачем Вы в Tag формы суете? Я же сказал: передайте в конструктор. И в конструкторе же форму и создавайте, раз данные из неё используете по ходу выполнения. И какое отношение (this.Tag) имеет к f2?